# SQL parameters - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some trouble. This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    fa.fam_label_!$ AS name,
    fa.dom_id AS id_lvl_1,
    fa.dom_code AS commodity_level_1,
    fa.fam_id AS id_lvl_2,
    fa.fam_code AS commodity_level_2,
    fa.sfam_id AS id_lvl_3,
    fa.sfam_code AS commdotiy_level_3,
    fa.ssfam_id AS id_lvl_4,
    fa.ssfam_code AS commodity_level_4
FROM 
    x_fam_all AS fa 
WHERE 
    fa.ssfam_code = 'HR_O28'
```

And I have to do with parameters but I don't know how it exactly works.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this really your column name `fam_label_!$` ? You can't reference a column name like that. You need to enclosed it in `[ ]`

Comment: Yes it is because i have few column in different language: fam_label_en, fam_label_fr etc

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @InFamCode varchar(10);
SET @InFamCode='HR_O28';
SELECT fa.fam_label_!$ AS name,
fa.dom_id AS id_lvl_1,
fa.dom_code AS commodity_level_1,
fa.fam_id AS id_lvl_2,
fa.fam_code AS commodity_level_2,
fa.sfam_id AS id_lvl_3,
fa.sfam_code AS commdotiy_level_3,
fa.ssfam_id AS id_lvl_4,
fa.ssfam_code AS commodity_level_4
FROM x_fam_all AS fa 
WHERE fa.ssfam_code = @InFamCode;
```

I guess, it should be something like this